# SQL index both columns in a two column table

Tags: mysql, indexing

My SQL database looks like this:

- column userID - integer, auto-increment, primary key
- column userUUID - uuid v4, unique for each user

(each uuid would appear about 100 times somewhere else, that's why i'm using integers)
Obviously, queries like this will be fast because of indexing a primary key:

```sql
SELECT userUUID FROM userIDmap WHERE userID = 12345
```

How can I make the inverse lookup efficient?

```sql
SELECT userID FROM userIDmap WHERE userUUID='0415db9d-83e0-4592-97dc-168f3e72defd'
```

The table has few million rows.
Is creating a new index enough?

Comment: You simply require a covering index on userUUID, userID.

Comment: Just an index on userUUID should be sufficient, since userID is the primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),
UNIQUE(uuid)
```

and

```
PRIMARY KEY(uuid),
INDEX(id)
```

are virtually identical in space, speed, etc.

Each will be implemented as two BTrees, one with (id, uuid), the other with (uuid, id).  Note that one BTree is great for the lookup one way, the other is equally great for the opposite lookup.

The one thing you *can* do is to shrink the uuid from `CHAR(36)` down to `BINARY(16)`.  In MySQL 8.0, see the functions `UUID_TO_BIN` and the reverse.  For MariaDB 10.7, there is a uuid datatype that takes core of it for you.  Before 8.0 / 10.7, see [*UUIDs*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) .  The shrinking helps significantly with size, hence slightly improving speed.

Note that InnoDB quietly tacks on the column(s) of the `PRIMARY KEY` onto each secondary index.

MySQL/MariaDB uses UUID v1; shuffling the bits can make new UUIDs roughly chronological.  This helps performance in some large datasets.  UUID v4 does not gain the same "locality of reference" benefit.  But the shrinking works the same way (and it does not matter that the bits are shuffled when packed into Binary).

**Separate table?**

You are adding a separate table just to map UUIDs into ids.  After that, you use the smaller ids in multiple tables.  Is that *separate* table really necessary?  Maybe.  Maybe not.

Plan A:  Separate table to map UUID to id.

```
CREATE TABLE lookup (
    id .. AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    uuid .. UNIQUE )

CREATE TABLE main (
    id .. PRIMARY KEY
    .... _
```

To lookup via UUID, either to a separate `SELECT` to get the `id`, or do a `JOIN`.

Plan B: No extra table

```
CREATE TABLE
    id .. AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    uuid .. UNIQUE,
    ...
```

To lookup via UUID, use a single `SELECT id, ... WHERE uuid=...`  For further activity, use the `id` tha that SELECT provided.

Note also that the secondary index (for uuid) is a BTree identical to one of the two BTrees in Plan A's `lookup`.

The details in your Plans A and B may have some wrinkles that I overlooked.  But offhand, I would say that Plan B is better.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to use the UUID data type, however using BINARY(16) seems reasonable. If the uuids are generated from outside source, would I still need to create a separate index for it, given how random are they?